# Is it possible to turn the set $\mathbb{Hom}(R,S)$ of ring homomorphisms from $R$ to $S$ into a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it possible to turn the set $\mathbb{Hom}(R,S)$ of ring homomorphisms from $R$ to $S$ into a ring? Discuss.

What I have observed that if I define the multiplication in $\mathbb{Hom}(R,S)$ s.t $fg(x)=f(x)g(x)$ $\forall x\in R$. Now,

$$
\begin{align*}
fg(x+y)=f(x+y)g(x+y)
\Rightarrow f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y)=f(x)g(x)+f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)+f(y)g(y) \Rightarrow f(x)g(y)=-f(y)g(x) \qquad\forall x,y\in R
\end{align*}
$$

So is it the sufficient condition?

Comment: how about composition?

Comment: It will not work. Find why?

Comment: See $R$ & $S$ are different.

Comment: If $R=S$ then it is true.

Comment: Are $R$ and $S$ commutative? Is $\hom$ the set of ring homomorphisms, or of abelian group homomorphisms?

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a *set* and $S$ a ring then the set $Map\left(R,S\right)$
of $S$-valued functions has a ringstructure if sums and products
of the functions are defined pointwise. If there is a ringstructure
on $R$ as well and $Hom\left(R,S\right)$ denotes the set of ringhomomorphisms
one could wonder whether $Hom\left(R,S\right)$ can be recognized
as a subring of $Map\left(R,S\right)$. If we are dealing with rings
with identity then for this $Hom\left(R,S\right)$ needs to contain
the map that serves as identity of $Map\left(R,S\right)$ wich is
prescribed by $r\mapsto1_{S}$ for each $r\in R$. However, this is
*not* a ringhomomorphism, because it lacks the property of sending $0_{R}$
to $0_{S}$.

Comment: The zero map is also not a ring homomorphism unless $S=0$.

Comment: I can't understand. What is your conclusion. How can I make $Hom(R,S)$ a ring?

Comment: My conclusion is that in general $Hom(R,S)$ is *not* a ring if it is equipped with the addition and multiplication that you propose. This because it has no identity. I don't see natural ways to make a ring of set $Hom(R,S)$. Also see the answer of @martin. The homset is empty there and every underlying set of a ring is non-empty.

Comment: If $R$ and $S$ do not have $1_R$ & $1_S$, then what is the problem? Why zero map is not a ring homomorphism?

Comment: The zero map is not a homomorphism because it sends identity to $0$ instead of $1$. Also in rings without identity your idea is not fruitful. If you are doing it with rings without identity then realize that the necessary condition that you mention in your question:
$\forall x\forall y\; f\left(x\right)g\left(y\right)+f\left(y\right)g\left(x\right)=0$
and this for **every pair** of homomorphisms $f,g$ is very very demanding.
It implies for instance that $f\left(x\right)^{2}=0$ is true for
every $x$ every homomorphism $f$ (this by taking $f=g$ and $x=y$).
And probably that's not all.

Answer (score 2):

$\hom_{\mathrm{Ring}}(\mathbb{F}_2,\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$.

Comment: Why zero map is not a ring homomorphism?

Comment: I think the $f(1_{\Bbb F_2})$ should be the identity of $f(\Bbb F_2)$ so it is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: $\mathsf{Ring}$ denotes the category of rings, i.e. objects are rings (having a unit by definition) and morphisms are homomorphisms of rings (preserving the unit by definition). If $\mathsf{Rng}$ denotes the category of non-unital rings, then in fact we have $\hom_{\mathsf{Rng}}(\mathbb{F}_2,\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$.

Comment: I can't understand your point. Probably you are not getting my question or confusion or I am not getting what you exactly want to say.

Comment: In $\Bbb F_2$ & $\Bbb Z$ both have unity. Again if the only ring homomorphism is zero homomorphism. Then in $r\mapsto 0$ the unity is $0$ in $f(R)$.

Comment: For me and approx. 90% of all mathematicians rings are unital and ring homomorphisms preserve the unit. Thus, if $\mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism, then $2 \mapsto 2$ but also $2=0 \mapsto 0$, so that $2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, a contradiction. Hence, $\hom(\mathbb{F}_2,\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$ and in particular this set carries no group structure, let alone a ring structure.